# Is there a reliable way to detect if a user is not using a web app?

Tags: language-agnostic

Is there a reliable way to to know whether a web page has the user's focus or not? E.g., are they in another tab or using another program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a plugin like [jquery.nap](http://www.frebsite.nl/werk/scripts/jquery_nap_plugin/index_en.php) may help you out in your quest

```
jQuery.nap is a plugin that detects when the user is "taking a nap"
and executes the defined functions when the user "falls asleep"
and "wakes up"
```

check also [jQuery.idleTimer](http://paulirish.com/2009/jquery-idletimer-plugin/).

I hope this will help you

Jerome Wagner

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but I'm not sure if it's viable. You could, on every user click/focus, send an AJAX request telling your back-end that the user done something. But this would cause an overhead of your client browser and you server.

Comment: I don’t need to know, server-side.